# Dynamic button click event within a timer tick event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a grid with 9 buttons. In the timer tick event a random button is higlighted. If one clicks the higlighted button, a dynamic click event is created and within the click event the button is marked with a different color. The counterHits variable in the dynamic button click event is supposed to keep track of the highlighted buttons that were hit. Sometimes though it increases the variable more than by one. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any help anyone?

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    const int buttons = 9;
    int counterHits;
    int counterTicks;    
    int currentIndex;
    int lastIndex;
    bool hit = false;
    Random r;

    Timer timerGameLoop;
    Timer timerUpdateUI;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timerGameLoop = new Timer();
        timerGameLoop.Interval = 1000;
        timerGameLoop.Tick += t_Tick;

        timerUpdateUI = new Timer();
        timerUpdateUI.Interval = 10;
        timerUpdateUI.Tick += timerUpdateUI_Tick;

        r = new Random();

    }

    // set up the grid and start
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons; i++)
        {
            var b = new Button();
            b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            b.Margin = new Padding(0);
            b.BackColor = Color.White;
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(b);
        }
        timerGameLoop.Start();
        timerUpdateUI.Start();
    }


    // tick event ui update loop
    void timerUpdateUI_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblHitCounter.Text = "hits : " + counterHits.ToString();
        lblTickCounter.Text = "ticks : " + counterTicks.ToString();
    }

    // tick event game loop
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // reset to white background if not clicked
        if (!hit)
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls[lastIndex].BackColor = Color.White;
        // highlight button to be clicked
        currentIndex = r.Next(buttons);
        lastIndex = currentIndex;
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls[currentIndex].BackColor = Color.Violet;

        // highligted button clicked
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls[currentIndex].Click += b_Click;

        hit = false;
        counterTicks++;
    }


    // highlighted button clicked event
    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = (Button)sender;
        b.BackColor = Color.Olive;
        hit = true;
        counterHits++;
        b.Click -= b_Click;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines attaches `b_Click` to your button. That eventhandler is only removed if you press the button

```
flowLayoutPanel.Controls[currentIndex].Click += b_Click;
```

See the implementation of `b_Click`

```
    // highlighted button clicked event
    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stugg
        b.Click -= b_Click;←Removed Here only if it is pressed
    }
```

This line indicates that some buttons have more than one EventHandler attached. Therefore when you click the button eventhandler runs more than once.

Comment: thank you Hasan, but I am not quite sure how to resove the issue with the answer given.

Comment: @GonzoGonschior, Before proceeding further, I would like to confirm that you see the problem with multiple click event being added to the same button?

Comment: Yes now I can see that. And I think now I have identified the problem. If the random object generates the same number after each other a second handler will be added to the same button object, hence there will be multible listernes to the same button instance.

Comment: @GonzoGonschior that is exactly what happens!

Comment: I would have one follow up question. Is there any way to check how many listeners that are subscribed to a dynamically created event?